# Using one variable for two numbers to manipulate

Tags: batch-file

I'm not sure if this can be done this way or done this way in batch. I have a script for user to enter two numbers in the same variable, or must they be treated as string that can be split up or concatenated? For example if the user enters "5 6" for the %math% variable, can these two be say, added or subtracted and echoed? Here's my code. I only included the "for /f" statement to try and break down what was inside the %math% variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:main
set /p math=Enter two numbers 
set /p operand=Enter operand (subtract sign, etc)
echo %math%
echo %operand%
pause

for /f "tokens=2, delims= " %%a in %math% do echo %%a

pause
echo.
pause
goto eof
endlocal

:eof
exit
```

Comment: `for %%a in (%math%) do echo %%a`?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%math%") do set /a result=%%a %operand% %%b`?

Comment: `set /A "result=!math: =%operand%!"` with Delayed Expansion enabled...

Comment: Thanks all. I'll try some of this code and see what happens.

Comment: thanks stephan and Aacini! it worked.

Comment: Like I said, it worked, but I was wondering what the statement that reads:   set /A "result=!math: =%operand%!" does? Can you break this one down for me?